# Prepared Statement Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference.

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

Getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ppa\php\process_images.php on line 29

Simply trying to update a database record, the following debug code

```
$id = (int)$x;
echo $id.". Type: ".gettype($id);
```

produces this: 4. Type: integer
So the variable is the correct type.

Here is my code

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    //Delete the image, first update the database, then move the image to a new folder. 
    foreach($_POST['product'] as $x) {
        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE images SET dodelete = ? WHERE id = ?")) {
            $id = (int)$x;
            echo $id.". Type: ".gettype($id);
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", 1, $id);   <---- line 29
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        } else {
            echo "Unable to delete image!";
        }
    }
}
```

At first I was binding the $x variable directly from the foreach statement, which I thought was the issue as the error says it can't pass parameter by reference, but as you can see I made a new variable $id.

Comment: Where is the processimage.php code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$stmt->bind_param("ii", 1, $id);
                     ---^
```

It's because 1 is not a parameter, it's an integer. You'll need to use bindValue instead.

Comment: Ah thanks, I changed it to 
$deletedVal = 1;
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $deletedVal, $id);